# How can I have 2 different font sizes and a line-break on a textarea placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was asked to do what you see in the screenshot. It is new to me. It is a placeholder with a line-break and 2 different font sizes.

```html
<div class="form-group pop-label">
  <textarea id="inquiry-store-location" class="form-control" name="store_location" placeholder="Store or Location" required></textarea>
  <label for="inquiry-store-location">Store or Location</label>
</div>
```

That's how my code/HTML looks so far.

Any ideas?

This is a screenshot of the design:

[image]

Comment: Ah. So the screenshot is a textarea, and you want to achieve the text inside of it (e.g, a placeholder)?

Comment: Yeah sorry. That's a screenshot of the design. And I need to achieve exactly that.

Comment: Well it is not going just be something with a textarea, going to involve other elements.

Comment: What is the use case? Like, if the user clicks anywhere inside of that box, all of that text disappears and it just essentially becomes a textarea?

Comment: Position the label up, add a bunch of padding to the textarea when empty

Comment: Here's how I would do it: first, design your 'overlay' element - the element that's going to have all the html and styles you need to go over your textarea. Then, have a function to hide and show this overlay. Then, you're going to have to do some javascript for when the text area gets focus and when it loses focus -- when it gets focus, hide the overlay. When it loses focus, check if there's any text in the textarea, and conditionally hide or show the overlay

Comment: What happens when it is focused? Label goes away?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to alter the textarea to have two different text sizes. Closest you can get with placeholder is just two lines of text.

T get what you want, the basic idea is to move the label up and add padding to the textarea to move the placeholder down.

It is unclear what you want to happen when the user enters text into the textarea.

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.pop-label {
  position: relative;
}

.pop-label label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: .5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group pop-label">
  <textarea id="inquiry-store-location" class="form-control" name="store_location" placeholder="I like to eat cheese on crackers." required></textarea>
  <label for="inquiry-store-location">Store or Location</label>
</div>
```

If you want the text to disappear when they add text

```css
.pop-label {
  position: relative;
}

.pop-label textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.pop-label textarea:invalid {
  height: 100px;
  width: 270px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}


.pop-label textarea + label {
  display: none;
}

.pop-label textarea:invalid + label {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 1em;
  left: .5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group pop-label">
  <textarea id="inquiry-store-location" class="form-control" name="store_location" placeholder="I like to eat cheese on crackers." required></textarea>
  <label for="inquiry-store-location">Store or Location</label>
</div>
```

Now you could use a trick like this, but you will not get full control over the text and size.

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group pop-label">
  <textarea id="inquiry-store-location" class="form-control" name="store_location" placeholder="  &#10;&#10;I like to eat cheese on crackers." required></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need. I made it using javascript. But this is not a complete answer. I am currently trying to figure out how to change the font of an ordinary string variable.

```js
let ph_1 = 'Placeholder_1';
let ph_2 = ' \n\nPlaceholder_2';
let ph_full = ph_1 + ph_2;
textarea_input = document.querySelector('#inquiry-store-location');

textarea_input.setAttribute('placeholder', ph_full);
```

```css
#inquiry-store-location {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group pop-label">
  <textarea id="inquiry-store-location" class="form-control" name="store_location" placeholder="" required></textarea>
</div>
```